# Is it possible to make and if/else before copying one column over an other?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Is it possible to make and if/else before copying one column over an other?

[I have an example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PMjgzBONdb0w8yqApWyrRjLTXRtwyIo7SyUM_5caaWw/edit?usp=sharing) to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM({
 IF(B!A2:A8<>""; 'C'!A2:A&" "&B!A2:A8; A!A2:A8)\
 IF(B!B2:B8<>""; 'C'!B2:B&" "&B!B2:B8; A!B2:B8)\
 IF(B!C2:C8<>""; 'C'!C2:C&" "&B!C2:C8; A!C2:C8)\
 IF(B!D2:D8<>""; 'C'!D2:D&" "&B!D2:D8; A!D2:D8)\
 IF(B!E2:E8<>""; 'C'!E2:E&" "&B!E2:E8; A!E2:E8)}))
```

which can be just:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(
 IF(B!A2:E8<>""; 'C'!A2:E&" "&B!A2:E8; A!A2:E8)))
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OKB2A-o3h8FH9YK-pQ6WbqxWkmUS7i3W9xW8HEtdptI/edit#gid=1880239088https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OKB2A-o3h8FH9YK-pQ6WbqxWkmUS7i3W9xW8HEtdptI/edit#gid=1880239088)